# Question about triple exponent

Tags: calculus

Why is this equality correct, assuming that    a, n, p > 0 (positive)

$$
\left(a^{n^{p}} \right )^{1/n}  = a^{n^{p-1}} 
$$

Comment: What is $n^{-1}$. it is ...

Answer (score 5):

Looking at just the exponent: $\displaystyle n^p \cdot \frac1n = n^p \cdot n^{-1} = n^{p-1}$

Thus, we have $a^{n^{p-1}}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(a^{n^{p}} \right )^{1/n}=a^{\frac{n^{p}}{n}}= a^{n^{p-1}} $$